# How to reduce the height of background gradient?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

In WordPress post, using "Info Box" from Visual composer plugin, I created a page (http://padals.com/t2/).

I want to reduce the height of background gradient so that the image can be displayed over the gradient background.

For example: http://www.saavn.com/s/album/tamil/Baahubali---The-Beginning-2015/WZFMlXk24SY_

I tried to reduce the padding-bottom of gradient background element, but no use. Please compare both the links, so you can understand what I am expecting.

Comment: for future reference, here's a screenshot of the example: https://gyazo.com/aae23379ca615867ea0f2d4ae73ffcf1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i see your background gradient is like this:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #6c6e73 0%, #969795 100%);
```

you can resize the background gradient like this:

```
background-size: 100% 120px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

or set absolute color-stops like this:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #6c6e73 0px, #969795 120px, #ffffff 120px);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "displayed separately overlay."

I'm assuming that you want to reduce the thickness of the grey background in the box element that is above, below, and to the left of the image at http://padals.com/t2/.

1)"I tried to reduce the padding-bottom, but no use."
    Of which element are you speaking.

2) Where is the code?

3) Make sure that the image's CCS rules aren't conflicting with each other.
--Check/adjust the margin of the grey/gradient element. 
--Check/adjust the border/padding of the image.
--Check/adjust other styling rules which might be overriding the element tags your working with.
ex:

stuff

The order of precedence goes from left to right inside the HTML tags.
With this example you would want to check all of the tags(article, p, span, a).

Comment: please see the example link so you can understand what I am expecting.